# Deflating POCO HttpResponse with gzip cuts the content

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib, poco, poco-libraries

I am using POCO 1.7.8 to write a HTTP server. Problem is when using gzip for deflating the response data:

```
std::string content = "HELLO WORLD, THIS IS LONGISH STRING THAT IS CUT";
response->set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
std::ostream& responseStream = response->send();
Poco::DeflatingOutputStream deflater(responseStream, Poco::DeflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
deflater << content;
deflater.close();
```

Response for the client is:

```
HELLO WORLD, THIS IS LONGISH STRING
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-csrftoken, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Connection: Close
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 07:52:17 GMT
```

If I change this to use ZLIB and set the Content-Encoding to deflate, the whole response is correctly returned from the server:

```
std::string content = "HELLO WORLD, THIS IS LONGISH STRING THAT IS CUT";
response->set("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
std::ostream& responseStream = response->send();
Poco::DeflatingOutputStream deflater(responseStream, Poco::DeflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_ZLIB);
deflater << content;
deflater.close();
```

Response for the client is:

```
HELLO WORLD, THIS IS LONGISH STRING THAT IS CUT
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-csrftoken, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Connection: Close
Content-Encoding: deflate
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 08:07:36 GMT
```

I tried to find examples how this should be done in the POCO server but couldn't find any and I am a bit stuck now with this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please rephrase to give more details on what goes wrong in which way, with which result, in contrast to what expectation. Currently your question sounds like what you attempt actually works: "the response is correctly returned from the server". This makes the problem and your question unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're setting the `Content-Length` header correctly for your compressed response? Alternatively try enabling chunked transfer encoding before calling `send()`.

`response->setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction. It seems that the Content-Length was wrong. According to RFC2616 the Content-Length should be smaller of 1024 or the compressed size. The example case works if I set the Content-Length to 1024, still need to write code for longer messages.

Comment: Problem with longer messages is that it's not possible to set headers after send is called. Also asking for tellp() from deflater always returns -1 so also a bit stuck here.

Comment: You either have to deflate into a buffer (string stream or temporary file) before sending the response to get the compressed content length, or use chunked transfer encoding. IMO chunked transfer encoding is the better option here.